# Crystal Report Selection Question

Tags: crystal-reports

If I had a single table of items ordered (let's call the table "items"), and there was a column within the table that tied the items in the same order together (order_id),  how would I select all orders that contained a certain "key" item?
In other words, I want to select orders that contain the "key" item and I want to see all the items with in that order, not just the "key" item.
For example, I want to select all grocery orders (and all the items within) where the person at least ordered "apples".

Comment: Is this using SQL or some sort of graphical query representation?

Comment: Belongs on StackOverflow. But the answer is you can't do this with a regular record selection formula. You'll need either your own SQL or some trickery with groups.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably (although I haven't tested it):

1. Add your table twice (so you will have two aliases pointing to the same table: `table_1, table_2`), joining on order_id
2. In your selection formula, use `{table_1.key} = "apples"`
3. Add a group on `{table_1.order_id}`
4. Use fields from `table_2` for the detail section

Alternatively, add the table once, select on `{table.key} = "apples"` and group by `{table.order_id}`.  Add a subreport in the group header linked by `{table.order_id}` to display the items.  This will be slower, but it will definitely give you what you want.